# git add, commit via expect script

Tags: git, bash, github, expect

in my work in order to use git, github we need to login, by using a function git_login < user_name > which is a built in function of a script named `git.sh`, then it asks for the user password.

I'm trying to automate this process, the expect script shows me that I logged in, but when trying to push or commit, it asks for password of unknown user, it should be simple right?!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 15
set tagName [[lindex $argv 0]
if { [llength $tagName] == 0 } {
    puts "no tag name provided...\n"
    exit 1
}
spawn /bin/bash -c "source git.sh && git_login my_user"
expect "assword: "
send -- "my_password"
expect "is now logged in"
exec git add .
exec git commit "$tagName"
exit
```

or instead of last 3 lines

```
git push origin "$tagName"
exit
```

I execute the script with `-d` instead of `-f` (for debug)

[image]

Comment: As per your debugging screenshot, you have a expect pattern for `is now logged in`. Have you missed that while posting it here ? Update it with the right script.

Comment: i agree that *it would be much easier to add screen shoot than explaining* but https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: as for the screenshot.. noted.., as for "is now logged in" apparently i have.. code fixed thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> the `expect` script shows me that I logged in

It doesn't apparently: it looks for the glob pattern "`is now logged in`" but does not find it.

The [`expect` automate tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) usually have a sequence like:

```
expect "password:"
# Send the password, and then wait for a shell prompt.
send "$my_password\r"
```

(not `expect "assword:"`)

Comment: yes it does...<br>as you can see one line after the line in green the pattern  "is now logged in"  is found, furthermore, just to be sure i added the P to assword and ran it again.. same result

Comment: @RamiHassan so what step of the script monitored by `expect` make git ask for a password? Is it possible this is a concurrency issue were expect detects git asking for a password, just before git *displays* the password request?

Comment: this part: spawn /bin/bash -c "source git.sh && git_login my_user", and i thought of that, the log_in is made by the script git.sh, i tried to add sleep before the commit/push part, didn't helped

Comment: @RamiHassan Within the `git_login my_user`, which line asks for a password?

Comment: if i run from the shell the function (git.sh script function) git_login user_x >> I'm prompted for a password for <user_x>, to be honest i think that i didn't get what you mean

Comment: @RamiHassan I meant, in that `git_login` script, is there *another* command which would prompt a *second* time for a password?